# R: Calculate rolling return for panel data with changing rolling window

Tags: r, dplyr, slider, window, rolling-computation

I have daily return data over a period of four years for a panel data set. Now I would like to calculate the annual return with a rolling window in the following way:

1. At the beginning, use 30 days as time window to calculate the rolling return by taking the average of the return and multiply by 250. I know I will lose the first 30 observations for that.
2. When I have more than 30 days for the rolling window (in my data it would be 30.09.2018) then use 31 days. On 01.10.2018 use 32 days etc. until you reach a time window of 250 days. Then keep 250 days as rolling window. Always compute the annual return by taking the average of the return in the time window and multiply by 250.

My data looks like this:
I haven't included all the dates as it would be to large to include here so there are only some dates in the data below.

```
structure(list(Date = c("31.08.2018", "01.09.2018", "02.09.2018", 
"03.09.2018", "04.09.2018", "05.09.2018", "06.09.2018", "07.09.2018", 
"08.09.2018", "09.09.2018", "10.09.2018", "11.09.2018", "12.09.2018", 
"13.09.2018", "14.09.2018", "15.09.2018", "16.09.2018", "17.09.2018", 
"18.09.2018", "19.09.2018", "20.09.2018", "21.09.2018", "22.09.2018", 
"23.09.2018", "24.09.2018", "25.09.2018", "26.09.2018", "27.09.2018", 
"28.09.2018", "29.09.2018", "30.09.2018", "01.10.2018", "02.10.2018", 
"03.10.2018", "04.10.2018", "05.10.2018", "06.10.2018", "07.10.2018", 
"31.08.2018", "01.09.2018", "02.09.2018", "03.09.2018", "04.09.2018", 
"05.09.2018", "06.09.2018", "07.09.2018", "08.09.2018", "09.09.2018", 
"10.09.2018", "11.09.2018", "12.09.2018", "13.09.2018", "14.09.2018", 
"15.09.2018", "16.09.2018", "17.09.2018", "18.09.2018", "19.09.2018", 
"20.09.2018", "21.09.2018", "22.09.2018", "23.09.2018", "24.09.2018", 
"25.09.2018", "26.09.2018", "27.09.2018", "28.09.2018", "29.09.2018", 
"30.09.2018", "01.10.2018", "02.10.2018", "03.10.2018", "04.10.2018", 
"05.10.2018", "06.10.2018", "07.10.2018"), Name = c("A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), Return = c(-0.021071566, 
0.005862582, -0.005960414, 0.012376918, 0.000768618, -0.005279988, 
-0.023441498, -0.006774054, -0.002641439, -0.003987006, -0.001579702, 
0.00533432, 0.01881727, 0.009697647, -0.008075897, 0.007608133, 
0.008286782, 0.003794405, -0.001018981, -0.007252921, -0.008454767, 
-0.002505217, -0.009758029, 0.000479896, -0.002947385, -0.009147111, 
0.008870721, -0.002740876, 0.006288296, 0.001098006, 0.001815974, 
0.005788253, 0.005000533, 0.005697275, 0.01245532, 0.002927324, 
-0.000641278, 0.005642696, -0.002631572, -0.004581003, -0.020361952, 
0.000433813, -0.00706271, 0.003822377, -0.004783566, -0.012040944, 
-0.016589789, 0.002386652, -0.003800319, -0.018014731, -0.001018981, 
-0.007252921, -0.008454767, -0.002505217, -0.009758029, 0.000479896, 
-0.002947385, -0.009147111, 0.008870721, -0.002740876, 0.006288296, 
0.001098006, 0.001815974, 0.005788253, 0.005000533, 0.005697275, 
0.01245532, 0.002927324, 0.006288296, 0.001098006, 0.001815974, 
0.005788253, 0.005000533, 0.006288296, 0.001098006, 0.001815974
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -76L))
```

I have started with the code below:

```
Data <- Data %>%
group_by(Name) %>%
mutate(Annual_Return=(mean(Return)*250)
```

However, I have difficulties to include the rolling window here. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `slider::slide_dbl` what you were looking for.

For example, `slide_dbl(1:10, mean, .before = 2, .after = 0)` returns

```
[1] 1.0 1.5 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0
```

that until be able to take a mean of three values, it takes mean till then.(`1->1`, `1 2 -> 1.5`)

So, for your data,

```
library(slider)
library(dplyr)
Data %>%
  group_by(Name) %>% # not sure if you want this
  mutate(ma = slider::slide_dbl(Return, mean, .before = 249, .after = 0) * 250) %>%
  dplyr::slice(-1:-29) # to remove first 29 rows per group that you want to start from 30 days

   Date       Name     Return       ma
   <chr>      <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 29.09.2018 A      0.00110  -0.278  
 2 30.09.2018 A      0.00182  -0.254  
 3 01.10.2018 A      0.00579  -0.201  
 4 02.10.2018 A      0.00500  -0.157  
 5 03.10.2018 A      0.00570  -0.111  
 6 04.10.2018 A      0.0125   -0.0185 
 7 05.10.2018 A      0.00293   0.00230
 8 06.10.2018 A     -0.000641 -0.00209
 9 07.10.2018 A      0.00564   0.0351 
10 29.09.2018 B      0.00293  -0.639  
11 30.09.2018 B      0.00629  -0.567  
12 01.10.2018 B      0.00110  -0.541  
13 02.10.2018 B      0.00182  -0.511  
14 03.10.2018 B      0.00579  -0.453  
15 04.10.2018 B      0.00500  -0.405  
16 05.10.2018 B      0.00629  -0.350  
17 06.10.2018 B      0.00110  -0.333  
18 07.10.2018 B      0.00182  -0.312
```

Comment: When I try to run the code with my original dataset, the rolling return only gets calculated after 250 days and all other rows above in the column ma are empty. Why is this the case? I am a bit confused since when I run the code with the data I provided here in the question, it is working.

Comment: I would understand it if I had .complete=TRUE but that is not in the code.

Comment: I could find the problem. I had missing data in certain rows.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you could use subsetting with an increasing index, here in base R.

```r
# list of indices
indices <- sapply(30:250, seq_len)
sapply(indices, function(i) mean(df$Return[i])*250)
#>   [1] -0.277943808 -0.254332927 -0.201164297 -0.157185583 -0.110670750
#>   [6] -0.018542157  0.002301542 -0.002093622  0.035084474  0.017315821
#>  [11] -0.011748344 -0.135620043 -0.129808774 -0.167852233 -0.142319358
#>  [16] -0.165732072 -0.227569114 -0.310970777 -0.292061740 -0.305490679
#>  [21] -0.389454520 -0.386813162 -0.414244260 -0.446309307 -0.449642546
#>  [26] -0.485821905 -0.475004121 -0.479597842 -0.510756116 -0.464511432
#>  [31] -0.468189892 -0.434742943 -0.423303516 -0.409378167 -0.380371270
#>  [36] -0.355286585 -0.328322867 -0.276947451 -0.262112474 -0.235530062
#>  [41] -0.228243896 -0.218634919 -0.195500222 -0.175697024 -0.152078497
#>  [46] -0.146390763 -0.138490970           NA           NA           NA
#>  [51]           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
#> ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I check it now with my real data